# Implementing signing logic for TZ4 (BLS12-381) Addresses using TypeScript

Tags: tezos-client, tezos-signer, cryptography, public-key

I was wondering if anyone has more detailed knowledge on signing logic and how `octez-client` derives public keys from a given `BLsk` prefixed secret key?

I've used a number of NPM packages that assist with those but don't seem to have any successes. A couple of them being:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chainsafe/bls
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@noble/bls12-381

No matter what I do it seems that I can't derive the correct PK from a given SK (compared to results from the `octez-client`), are there any steps that the `octez-client` take that I might be missing in my TS project?

In terms of `bls12-381` curve, can someone with more knowledge on the matter give a quick explanation to how `octez` utilizes it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding BLS signatures, Octez follows the [CFRG specification v4 about BLS signatures](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-bls-signature/04/). The OCaml library used is [ocaml-bls12-381-signature](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/cryptography/ocaml-bls12-381-signature). The current protocol (i.e. up to M while writing these lines) uses the version [v1.0.0](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/cryptography/ocaml-bls12-381-signature/-/blob/1.0.0) of the OCaml library.

The CFRG specification mentions different BLS signature schemes, one minimizing the size of the public key for a longer signature size, and one minimizing the signature size for a longer public key size. The library implements both, namely MinPk and MinSig. Octez uses the [MinPk](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/v15.1/src/lib_crypto/bls.mli#L30) for the moment.

For BLS signatures, private keys are elements of the scalar field of BLS12-381 and are 32 bytes long. The serialisation of a secret key (i.e. the process to get a string starting with `BLsk`) is a base58 encoding with the bytes prefix given [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/lib_crypto/base58.ml#L448), which are, in decimal, `\003\150\192\040`.

To get back the 32 secret key bytes, you have to base58 decode the `BLsk` value, and remove the prefix given above. The bytes must be interpreted in little endian, and they represent a scalar field element in decimal representation, see [the library documentation](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/cryptography/ocaml-bls12-381-signature/-/blob/1.0.0/src/bls12_381_signature.mli#L10).
From there, you can use the libraries you mention to derive the public key.

I do not know the libraries you mentioned and I am not an experienced TypeScript developer, but, with [noble-curves](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves), I suppose you should be able to derive the public key with the code following the README.md code sample. You might need to convert it in hexadecimal first.
It seems the [library only proposes the MinPk](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves/blob/main/src/abstract/bls.ts#L269) version of the specification, which is the one used by Octez. It would be nice if the library author could mention it in the documentation or make the API clear on this.
About [ChainSafe/bls][9], [based on the size in bytes of a compressed public key][10], it seems they also use MinPk.

Regarding your questions on the usage of BLS12-381 in Octez, there are different usecases, but not restricted to:

1. [Integration of opcodes in Michelson][11]. It allows you to use BLS12-381 in smart contract, and for instance, you could have an on-chain [Groth16 verifier][12].
2. BLS signatures using the pairing-friendly curves BLS12-381 are used [in smart rollups][13] to L2 aggregate signatures.

Comment: I couldn't post more than 10 links, therefore here the other links:
[9] https://github.com/ChainSafe/bls
[10]: https://github.com/ChainSafe/bls/blob/master/src/constants.ts#L2
[11]: https://tezos.gitlab.io/mumbai/michelson.html?highlight=bls12%20381#bls12-381-primitives
[12]: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/v15.1/tests_python/contracts_alpha/mini_scenarios/groth16.tz
[13]: https://tezos.gitlab.io/mumbai/smart_rollups.html

Comment: This question/answer is yet another concrete example of why the community desperately needs parts of the client split out into standalone modules in languages like C, C++ or Rust, that can be imported into other languages/projects. Expecting everyone in the community to have this level of skill/knowledge is why there is such a barrier to onboarding to Tezos

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SimonMcLoughlin. I do agree it would be nice to have more libraries to deal directly with the encoding. In the meantime, I would redirect to this link (https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/tree/master/scripts/b58_prefix) which, IMO, explain well how to decode/encode Octez related base58 encodings without going into too many details as I have done regarding BLS above. Do you think it is enough to cover the scope of this thread (i.e. encoding)?

Comment: I'm not sure who this would be targeted towards. As a frontend engineer with no knowledge of phyton or a crypto background, there is a lot of unnecessary information and terminology in the link that would be difficult for a novice to parse.  Again "it would be nice to have more libraries" - its not a nice to have, it was essential for this to exist 2 years ago, it should be far beyond top priority to produce such assets ASAP. This has been a frequent complaint resulting in the loss of a lot of talent in the tezos ecosystem as people simply cant figure out how to get started

Comment: If you are a frontend engineer, I would recommend you to have a look at Taquito (https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito), which, IMO, does a very good job. Feel free to open issues on their repository if you think there are missing features.

Comment: Taquito can't run natively on mobile or desktop, it requires poor technologies like ReactNative in order to make use of it. I have written many bits and pieces in native Swift already, manually copying/translating logic over by hand, I can speak to how truly difficult and utterly insane it is that such things are required. The core teams adding all these features should and must be the ones to provide reusable assets in a platform agnostic manner, and then rely on teams like Taquito to add platform specific pieces by wrapping it up. Expecting third party teams to do everything is not feasible